# Generate automatic records in a table in Django even if the system is not being used

Tags: django, python-3.x

Does anyone know a way to generate a record in a table without the system being used by the user?

I need to generate something similar to a notification or reminder, with various data obtained from other tables, something similar to a report

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run periodic tasks, you will need some sort of task scheduler like [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) or [huey](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.9/django.html). With that in place, you can just create and save instances of whatever model you have in mind from the task scripts and the task scheduler will repeat it periodically.